# AngularJS : ng-repeat for plain text

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I have:

```
app.controller('items', function($scope){
   $scope.items = [
      {'id':1, 'name':'randomOne'},
      {'id':2, 'name':'whatEverName'} 
   ];
});
```

What I want:

```
<input value="1,2"/>
```

I learn about `ng-repeat`, but it can be used only on html tags. Is there a way to achieve that with AngularJS?

Thanks!

Comment: `ng-repeat` is just a directive really so you would create your own which you can then attach to your `<input />` and have that directive generate the value attribute for the element based on the `items` So your template is still pretty clean and not all your controller needs some extra work to get the string in there.

Comment: What is the final purpose? Why do you need the values concatenated?

Comment: @Bonatoc In order to send them with the whole form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filter:

```
.filter('getIds', function () {
  return function (items) {
    return items && items.map(function (item) {
      return item.id;
    }).join(',');
  }
})
```

In your html:

```
<input value="{{ items | getIds }}" />
```

Example Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ifHKzWqxtErQQVToMNsH?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$scope.value = _.pluck(items, 'id').join(',');

<input value="value">
```

Comment: Looks very nice, but it crash the Javascript :(

Comment: Is there a way to do pluck without underscore.js?

Comment: I don't know. underscore/lodash is so useful I always include it in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through them and use `value="{{ids}}"` like:

```
$scope.ids = [];
angular.forEach($scope.items, function(values,keys){
     $scope.ids.push(values.id);
});
$scope.ids = $scope.ids.join();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/R9t4h/2/)